# Exchange 2003 - Virtual Pop Service doesn't restart

Tags: email, pop3, windows-services, exchange-2003

I have an interesting issue with one of the servers I look after. When the server is rebooted  the POP3 virtual server under Exchange System Manager does not start but the POP3 services under windows services does. Can anyone this what could possibly be causing this? There's nothing in the EV to suggest that anything untoward is happening.

Answer (score 0):

since both services use the same port, odds are the exchange pop3 service is trying to start but failing.  You should see an indication of this in the event log.  You can go in and set the IIS pop3 service to manual or disabled which would prevent the service from starting and likely allow the Exch pop3 to start...  Though it has been a while, I could have sworn they used the IIS POP3 service for Exchange, but I might be wrong on that.  If there are two, then you'll want Exch to start, not IIS.